# Is it possible to create a machine that converts one matter type to another?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

In general, there is no such thing as iron protons or aluminum electrons. There are different types of atoms, but the only thing that is different is how many of each thing there is.

Would it be possible, (and theoretically what would the process look like, precise lasers etc) to throw a clump of plastic bottles and random garbage into a container, strip the atoms down to base protons electrons etc, and build it back up on the other side into a clump of raw material that you would need like aluminum? (solving the issue of scarcity of resources, you can make anything, something else.)

Comment: This is called [nuclear transmutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation), stars are natural "machines" of this sort. But this seems like a question for Physics SE.

Comment: yeah i couldn't determine if it was appropriate, via Physics SE : "Is your question about physics?

We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed"

Comment: We have the same preference here, for questions about philosophy.

Comment: hence the tag : "for applied philosophical questions about the study of science, the pursuit of scientific knowledge, and the scientific method"

Comment: Cows input grass, water, and sunlight and output meat. Pretty good trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the systems theory perspective.

A coffee machine is a machine that can converts coffee, chocolate and milk into a cappuccino. We have the capacity to create some types of converters, so, we can "convert one matter type to another". But not in most cases. It's probably quite difficult to convert a cappuccino into coffee, chocolate and milk. *We can produce aluminum from bauxite*[1](https://rocksandminerals.com/MineralInformation/Aluminum/HowAluminumIsProcessed.html). But it's quite difficult to convert a gram of dust into pure energy.

Converting something means not to just reorganize parts, but usually to remove some parts, to add other parts and to process. A cow is able to convert grass into milk, which is not made of pure particles (or molecules, or atoms) of grass.

Nevertheless, you address *pure reorganization* (like rearranging a mess of apples into a pyramid of apples). In addition, you address a quite arbitrary target: reorganization of the parts forming atoms (quarks). It is arbitrary, because an atom is just a system with subsystems like any other, like a cloud, where the electromagnetic interactions seem to hold it as a unit.

You seem to assume that quarks/electrons are like balls of matter. That's false. In simple terms, atoms are not just small balls laying on the ground, but phenomena of energy, or in other words, let's say, balls+energy (*balls being also different forms of energy*). Reorganization is not such thing when it comes to atoms. If you want to change an element into another, you will usually need to inject or extract energy. So, you are making the same thing that a cow will do to convert grass into milk: you are adding, removing and processing parts.

In such case, yes, we can, but we are strongly limited by our knowledge of such domain. Radioactivity is an example: we know how to convert certain components into others, by rearranging the parts of atoms, or just how to generate a large amount of energy so to make a bomb. But AFAIK, (again, in simple words) *we still don't know how to reorganize quarks individually to modify atoms*.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would need to strip off all the electrons from the individual atoms in the random garbage, and then sort the bare nuclei into different mass groupings, and then figure out how to smash the right nuclei together in order to build up the nuclei you desire.

Smashing the nuclei together will only sometimes yield the bigger nucleus you want, other times the nuclei shatter into pieces of no use to you.

The amount of energy required to accomplish this would be stupendously large, and you'd need to perform the task in a heavy ion accelerator the size of a small city. It would require hundreds or thousands of hours of operation to yield microgram quantities of the desired atom, and there's a good chance that most of it would be of the wrong isotope. This means the atoms would be decaying spontaneously into something else you don't want, and emitting large quantities of deadly radiation in the process.